# How to manually modify a cell that is being edited in a worksheet_change event?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a bit of trouble and could use some help. I need to create code that changes the value of a named range based on the value of a cell. There are 4 options: A, B, C, and None. If A, B, or C are selected, I need a preset value input into the named range, change the color of the range to grey, and lock the cells. If None is selected, the named range will change to yellow, and the user will enter their own value into the named range. Below is the code I was trying:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

ws.Unprotect Password:="MyPass"

If ws.Range("L14") = "A" Then
    ws.Range("NamedRange").Rows(1) = "Option 1"
    
    ws.Range("NamedRange").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    ws.Range("NamedRange").Locked = True
    
ElseIf ws.Range("L14") = "B" Then
    ws.Range("NamedRange").Rows(1) = "Option 2"
    
    ws.Range("NamedRange").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    ws.Range("NamedRange").Locked = True

ElseIf ws.Range("L14") = "C" Then
    ws.Range("NamedRange").Rows(1) = "Option 3"

    ws.Range("NamedRange").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    ws.Range("NamedRange").Locked = True
    
Else 'user input own entries
    ws.Range("NamedRange").ClearContents
    ws.Range("NamedRange").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    ws.Range("NamedRange").Locked = False
End If

ws.Protect Password:="MyPass"

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The issue I'm having is when None is selected. The cells are changed to yellow and unlocked, but because I'm using the worksheet change event, any value I try to input gets automatically cleared. Is there any way to allow the user to change the named range when "None" is selected with the worksheet change event?

Comment: add a check to the color of `Target` and bypass your function if yellow.  Maybe here `Else 'user input own entries`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav thanks! I guess that was a pretty obvious fix, was just missing it. I added an IF statement to the final else, so if the color is yellow, it just skips the clearcontents, color assign, & unlock. It'll work the first time None is changed, but skip anytime after. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you do not use in your code the `Target` cell....  Do you want the event to be triggered by **all cells in the sheet** change? It would be good to start the event with the cote line : `If Target.Address <> "$L$14" Then Exit Sub`, being a sheet event, it is not need to use `ws` and qualify it. It refers to the active cell and it is enough to simple use `Range("L14")`. Then, the last `Else` does not refer to a change in "L14" as you probably want...

Test the last way, please:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target.Address <> "$L$14" Then Exit Sub
 Application.EnableEvents = False

 ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="MyPass"
 Select Case Target.Value
    Case "A"
        Range("NamedRange").rows(1) = "Option 1"
        
        Range("NamedRange").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        Range("NamedRange").Locked = True
    Case "B"
        Range("NamedRange").rows(1) = "Option 2"
    
        Range("NamedRange").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        Range("NamedRange").Locked = True
    Case "C"
        Range("NamedRange").rows(1) = "Option 3"

        Range("NamedRange").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        Range("NamedRange").Locked = True
    Case Else
        Range("NamedRange").ClearContents
        Range("NamedRange").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Range("NamedRange").Locked = False
 End Select

 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="MyPass"
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The code is not tested, but it should work, I think. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Thanks, this worked well and was definitely an improvement. Don't use too much VBA in my role and I think this is the first time I needed worksheet_change, so I wasn't aware of using the target cell - guess I should've done more research. Thanks!